# Control LED panels via a relay and a PIR sensor

Tags: led, relay

I bought 6 x 48W LED panels and a PIR motion sensor to light a shed/workshop area. All 240V rated.  I did not appreciate that the LED drivers have a high inrush current.  My question is whether I can place a non-latching relay between the PIR and the LED panels?  If so, please can you help me to spec the relay.  I don't know anything about the electrical properties of a relay, particularly whether the PIR could handle it.  This is the model of PIR, with its nominal ratings
http://www.timeguard.com/products/light/pir-presence-detectors/360-surface-mount-ceiling-pir-presence-detector

Alternatively, I could fit an inrush limiter but I would again need some help to spec it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's possible, but to get the relay ratings, we'd need the LED panel inrush current characteristics.  

One thing I notice on the timeguard sheet is they have no voltage ratings on the LED lamp switching, if DC it would make sense, but if you're switching the mains to the LED power supply you may be closer to the Incandescent/Halogen rating (unless there's a large reactive component to the LED power supply).  

Again, we'd need to know the LED side of the equation power supply, etc.

Comment: Thanks. The Long Life Lamp Company does not publish inrush figures.  Some Timeguard PIR specs don't mention LED but the SLW2300RF rates it at 2300W Halogen Lighting. 500W Fluorescent Lighting. 250W LED Lighting.  This suggests that LED panels have twice the inrush of Fluorescent light, which is what caught me out.  So, my 300W of LED panels equate to about 2700W halogen = 11A.  I therefore thought a 20A relay should be fine, but my question is whether the PIR can switch the relay.  I would guess so.  But it might be better to use a load controller but they are less available than relays.

Comment: Hi, Meanwhile I have found a relay that looks good: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/non-latching-relays/8287084/    It is suitable for high inrush currents and the coil has 21 kOhms, so I don't thing the PIR would have a problem, but please correct me if you think I'm wrong.  Also, I don't think my 13A domestic circuit would have trouble with an 11A inrush, but again please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Generally circuit breakers would not trip on a fast in-rush, so I'd say you're ok on that.  21Kohms on the coil resistance is fine, the PIR should have no problem switching that at all if it's designed for those other loads, and you won't have a heat dissipation issue (relay coil dissipation would be about 2.5W).

Comment: Thanks isdi!  In the end I selected a different relay from Finder (https://www.findernet.com).  For my 300W LED circuit I took their "13.91" a 10A/20 (80 - 5 ms) SPST-NO continuous impulse relay.  For the 600W LED circuit I got their "13.81" a similar 16A/30 (120 - 5 ms) relay.  I was never able to find an inrush current spec. for the LED drivers.  Seems to be working just fine.